# How to schedule a job to run and send out an email only when there are n rows in the table in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which is sent daily which has some no. of rows but I want to send a separate report with a subject which says it is "critical" as it has n no. of rows in it.

How do I schedule this in SSRS?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you simply add some conditional logic to your existing report?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Jini.  I expect that more information, such as details/code on your existing job, will help other provide great answers.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create a [data driven subscription](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187066(v=sql.105).aspx) that only returns results if your table contains n rows.

Comment: FYI, Data Driven Subscriptions are only available in the Enterprise version of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A Data Driven Subscription would be best if you have the Enterprise version of SQL, but if you don't you'll need to get creative. One method that should work is to create a copy of the existing report (if it's **TheNinjaReport** call the copy **TheNinjaReport_Critical** or something), and alter the query so that it throws an error if there aren't the requisite number of rows. When the query throws an error, the subscription will fail and nothing will go to the end user. Something like

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ErrorLog) > 100
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.ErrorLog
ELSE
    RAISERROR('Not a critical number of errors', 16, 1)
```

This is not ideal because now you have two reports to maintain, but it will get you where you need to be.